# How to add multiple files from multiple directories into svn changelist?

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

I want to add and commit files which are present in different directories using changelist. I have written code in .bat file, you can find the example code below

```
svn add dem.txt
cd demo/docu
svn add dem.py
svn changelist mychangelist dem.py ../../dem.txt
```

i am checking the files which are present in the changelist by

```
svn st --changelist mychangelist
```

it gives

```
 --- Changelist 'mychangelist':
 A       dem.py
```

but it is not showing dem.txt in the mychangelist.

Process i followed is it correct or any other problems in mycode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type:

```
cd ..\..
```

Then try again:

```
svn status --changelist mychangelist
```

The output will be something like:

> ```
> --- Changelist 'mychangelist':
> A       dem.txt
> A       demo/docu/dem.py
> ```

The `svn status` command looks in the current directory and its sub-directories, but not in higher directory levels. The command `svn status --changelist` does not look for the given changelist and displays the contained items, rather it looks for items in the current directory tree and displays those that are listed in the given changelist. If you think like that you understand why the command behaves like this.

To prove this, try this (after having done the above mentioned `cd` command line):

```
svn status --non-recursive --changelist mychangelist
```

Which will produce the following output:

> ```
> --- Changelist 'mychangelist':
> A       dem.txt
> ```